# Insert new element after each nt-h array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called `a` and I want to insert an element after every `nt-h` elements of the array `a`. For example, I want to put the string `XXX` after each `3` elements of the array `a` and as result get a new array `b` as shown on the next example:

```js
let a = [undefined, "", 0, [], "ee", false, null, {},  Date(), true, (z)=>2*z, Array(0), NaN ];

let b = [undefined, "", 0, "XXX", [], "ee", false, "XXX", null, {}, Date(), "XXX", true, (z)=>2*z, [], "XXX", NaN];

console.log(a, b);
```

I have tried to do it in this way:

```
b = [];
a.map((x, i) => b.push((i + 1) % 3 ? x : "XXX"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/vjfaqn3u/16/

However, there is a problem: *The output `b` array has the same length as input `a` which is wrong*. Any idea or alternative solution?

(UPDATE: in-place solutions are also ok; I cut array `a`)

Comment: `a.map` runs over every element of array `a`, meaning it will run exactly as many times as there are elements in the array. What your current code does is replace the value at the 15th spot with `XXX` rather than insert `XXX`

Comment: why not `a.splice(15,0,'XXX');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let a= [undefined, "", 0, [], "ee", false, null, {},  Date(), true, (z)=>2*z, Array(0), NaN ];
  
let n = 3+1;
let currentPosition = 3;
let temp ='xxxxxx';

console.log('Before assignment:::',a.length, a);

while(currentPosition <= (a.length+1)){
   a.splice(currentPosition,0,temp);
   currentPosition += n;
}

console.log('new array length:::::',a.length ,a);
```

I hope this solution will be fine for you. 
Before inserting the element a length is 13. After 17.

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution that uses a `while` loop with the [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method for insert the `token` every `N` elements. Also, the logic is wrapped inside a function.

```js
let insertTokenEveryN = (arr, token, n) => {

    // Clone the received array, so we don't mutate the
    // original one. You can ignore this if you don't mind.

    let a = arr.slice(0);
    
    // Insert the <token> every <n> elements.

    let idx = n;

    while (idx <= a.length)
    {
        a.splice(idx, 0, token);
        idx += n + 1;
    }

    return a;
};

let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
let res1 = insertTokenEveryN(array, "XXX", 2);
let res2 = insertTokenEveryN(array, "XXX", 3);
let res3 = insertTokenEveryN(array, "*", 4);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res3));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a better case for `reduce()` or just a `for` loop. `map()` will always give you a new array of the same size.  If you're careful with the ending and start you should be able to make it work in the general case with something like.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

function insert_after(arr, str, n){
    return arr.reduce((arr, item, i) =>{
        arr.push(item)
        if (i % n == n-1) arr.push(str)
        return arr
    }, [])  
}

console.log(insert_after(arr, 'x', 2).join(','))
console.log(insert_after(arr, 'x', 3).join(','))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you push instead but not after the element.
If you want to use `map` you can use `apply` to push either one or two element

```js
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = []
a.map((x,i)=> Array.prototype.push.apply(b, (i+1)%3 ? [x] : [x, "XXX"]))
console.log(b.join(', '))
```

Comment: The use of `map()` is confusing here since. Since you are ignoring the return value, why not use the more appropriate `forEach`?

Answer (score 1):

As per the given example arrays **a** and **b**, you can try the below code to get the expected output.

```
let a= [undefined, "", 0, Array(0), "eeeeeeeeee", null, "cccccccc", "bbbbbbb", "ddddddddd", Array(0), "bbbbbbb", {}, undefined, "bbbbbbb", {}, null, 0, "ddddddddd", null, "eeeeeeeeee", "ddddddddd", "bbbbbbb", undefined, "cccccccc", "ddddddddd", "ddddddddd", undefined, undefined, "eeeeeeeeee", {}, "", "", undefined, "", "eeeeeeeeee", undefined, Array(0), Array(0), 0, "ddddddddd", "", "", null, null, "bbbbbbb", "", Array(0), null, "ddddddddd", {}];
    let b = [];
    let j = 0, insertIndex = 15;
    let insertVal = "INSERT_VAL";
    for(let i=0; i< a.length;){
        b[j++] = a[i++];
        if(i%insertIndex ==0){
            b[j++] = insertVal;
        }
    }
    console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by answers [Hamlet Hakobyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892358/860099) and [Mark Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892325/860099) I provide **oneliners** for immutable solutions using map and reduce (time complexity *O(n)*)

```
let b=[]; a.forEach((x,i)=>b.push(x,...(i+1)%k ? [] : ["XXX"]));  

let c = a.reduce((t,x,i)=>t.push(x,...(i+1)%k ? [] : ["XXX"])&&t, []);
```

and in-place solution (result in `a`, complexity *O(n/k)* )

```
for(let i=a.length/k|0; i; i--) a.splice(i*k,0,"XXX");
```

I read all of your answer and give +1 because they was interesting, it was hard to choose best but finnaly I choose [Amaranadh Meda answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892548/860099) because he first shows that we can reduce time complexity from *O(n)* to *O(n/k)* where n is size of array `a` and `k` is size of gap between new inserted elements.

```js
let a= [undefined, "", 0, [], "ee", false, null, {},  Date(), true, (z)=>2*z, Array(0), NaN ]; 

let k=3; // gap

// immutable -> result in b
let b=[]; a.forEach((x,i)=>b.push(x,...(i+1)%k ? [] : ["XXX"]));  
let c = a.reduce((t,x,i)=>t.push(x,...(i+1)%k ?[] : ["XXX"])&&t, []);


// in-place -> result in a
for(let i=a.length/k|0; i; i--) a.splice(i*k,0,"XXX"); 

console.log('b=',b);
console.log('c=',c);
console.log('a=',a);
```