# Functional way to Insert a value between all the elements inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

Let's say that I have the following array:

```
const myArray = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"]
```

What I would like to do is to add an element between all the elements, like this:

```
myArray.someMethod("XXX")
// ["q", "XXX", "w", "XXX", "e", "XXX", "r", "XXX", "t", "XXX", "y"]
```

In a way, it is kinda what `.join` does, but I would like the output to be another array, instead of a string.

I know how to do this with a loop, but I would like to know is the "functional" way to achieve this.

Comment: Some time ago, I made a generalized method for this, you could check it if you like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892270/insert-new-element-after-each-nt-h-array-element/53892730#53892730

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of an iterative approach, you could take a recursive approach by taking rest parameters and a check for the length of the rest array.

```js
const
    zip = ([a, ...r], v) => r.length ? [a, v, ...zip(r, v)] : [a];

console.log(zip(["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"], 'XXX'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

In a functional programming way, an Array is a [Monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads) which means it is flatMappable. [FlatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is an implementation of a Monadic bind operator which for an Array it maps an element to a new array and flatten them together.

With this idea, you just need to add a new value to the output array inside the flatMap function. See following

```
Array.prototype.someMethod = function(a){ return this.flatMap(i => [i,a]) }

myArray.someMethod("XXX")
// Array(12) [ "q", "XXX", "w", "XXX", "e", "XXX", "r", "XXX", "t", "XXX", … ]
```

The above example adds the XXX at the end of the Array, so we can ignore the last element from being padded by making use of the index argument of the flatMap as follows

```
Array.prototype.someMethod = function(a){ let L=this.length; return this.flatMap((n,i) => (i<L-1) ? [n,a] : [n]) }

myArray.someMethod("XXX")
// Array(11) [ "q", "XXX", "w", "XXX", "e", "XXX", "r", "XXX", "t", "XXX", "y"]
```

Comment: This is nice, but will append `"XXX"` to the end as well, won't it?

Comment: It's exciting to see people using monads in Javascript :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` with `.concat()`:

```js
const data = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"];
const str = "XXX";

const insertValue = (arr, val) => [].concat(
    ...arr.map((v, i) => (i > 0 ? [str, v] : v))
);

console.log(insertValue(data, str));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"]
const joinStr = 'xxx';
console.log(myArray.join(','+ joinStr + ',').split(','));
```

Comment: Will not work if `,`-the _glue_ is contained by any of the array element.

Comment: @Tushar yes but you can change it to any unique kind of  ```"glue"```. ```,``` is what I used for this example it can be sothing like ```@%``` may be.

Comment: True. However, if data is coming from third-party service or it is user-entered, then you cannot guarantee about the uniqueness of the _glue_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map() with flat()

```
const myArray = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"];
const newArray = myArray.map((i) => {
   return [i, 'xxx']
}).flat();

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: I did not know `flat()`! That helps a lot. Even though the solution is not correct because it would also introduce the "glue" at the end of the array.

Comment: Note that [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is an _experimental technology_ and won't be supported by all browsers.

Comment: I hope that babel can transpile it safely

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` to transform the original array and either put it in a two argument function or add it as a method of `Array.prototype` (if you really want the call method in the post):

```js
const myArray = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"]

// A function taking array and glue arguments

const interpose = (array, glue) => array.reduce(
   (acc, c,i,a) => (
        acc.push(c) && (i < a.length -1) && acc.push( glue),
        acc
    ), []
);

// As an array method

Array.prototype.interpose = function( glue) {
    return  this.reduce(
    (acc, c,i,a) => (
         acc.push(c) && (i < a.length -1) && acc.push( glue),
         acc
     ), []);
}

// Test

console.log( 'interpose( myArray, "XXX" = %s', interpose( myArray, "XXX"));
console.log( 'myArray.interpose("XXX")  = %s', myArray.interpose("XXX"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join, since the default character of joining is *comma,* then change by surrounding each comma with `','+glue+','` finally split it by *comma*.

```js
const myArray = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"]

Array.prototype.someMethod = function(glue){
    return this.join().replaceAll(',',','+glue+',').split(',');
} 

console.log(myArray.someMethod("XXX"))
// ["q", "XXX", "w", "XXX", "e", "XXX", "r", "XXX", "t", "XXX", "y"]
```